# Selecting rows where a field value appears in at least 4 other rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL statement that gets me to table of results like this...

```
categoryID | subCategoryID | categoryName
-------------------------------------------
1          | 2             |  Animals & Pets
1          | 7             |  Animals & Pets
1          | 10            |  Animals & Pets
1          | 11            |  Animals & Pets
4          | 0             |  Books & Magazines
4          | 0             |  Books & Magazines
4          | 0             |  Books & Magazines
4          | 0             |  Books & Magazines
4          | 31            |  Books & Magazines
4          | 32            |  Books & Magazines
4          | 33            |  Books & Magazines
5          | 0             |  Chemist
6          | 0             |  Cloths & Accessories
6          | 0             |  Cloths & Accessories
6          | 656           |  Cloths & Accessories
7          | 0             |  Collectables
7          | 0             |  Collectables
7          | 0             |  Collectables
8          | 0             |  Computer
8          | 0             |  Computer
8          | 0             |  Computer
8          | 0             |  Computer
8          | 0             |  Computer
8          | 0             |  Computer
8          | 56            |  Computer
8          | 60            |  Computer
8          | 61            |  Computer
```

I now want to get only the rows where there are at least 4 distinct ID's in the subCategoryID column sharing the same categoryID, and then group them by the categoryID. For example turning the above table into...

```
categoryID | subCategoryID | categoryName
-------------------------------------------
1          | 2             |  Animals & Pets
4          | 0             |  Books & Magazines
8          | 0             |  Computer
```

My SQL so far is..

```
SELECT
    listing.categoryID,
    listing.subCategoryID,
    categoryName
FROM listing
LEFT JOIN productInfo USING (listingID)
LEFT JOIN sectionCategory USING (categoryID)
WHERE listing.categoryID > 0
AND listing.listingStatus = 'A'
AND listing.pauseReason = 'A'
AND productInfo.quantity > 0
ORDER BY categoryID, subCategoryID
```

I've tried using...

```
SELECT
    listing.categoryID,
    categoryName
FROM listing
LEFT JOIN productInfo USING (listingID)
LEFT JOIN sectionCategory USING (categoryID)
WHERE listing.categoryID > 0
AND listing.listingStatus = 'A'
AND listing.pauseReason = 'A'
AND productInfo.quantity > 0
GROUP BY listing.categoryID
HAVING count(*) >= 4
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 6
```

But it only seems to remove the categories that have a listing count of less than 4. Any ideas?

Comment: 4 doesn't have 4 distinct sub category IDs, why is it selected.

Comment: Did you try dumping the result into a where loop?  If you want each entry listed individually, then do a counter loop inside of it.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the values incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Having` clause to filter the `categoryID` which is having atleast 4 distinct `subCategoryID`.  Try this.

```
select categoryID , categoryName
from yourtable
group by categoryID , categoryName
having count(distinct subCategoryID)>= 4
```

But am not sure how you `categoryID=4` in expected output.

If you want atleast 4 `subCategoryID` per `category` may not be `distinct` then use this.

```
select categoryID , categoryName
from yourtable
group by categoryID , categoryName
having count(subCategoryID)>= 4
```

Comment: Ah, that was my mistake in copying the table. The subCategoriyIDs are 0, 31,32,33 respectively for category = 4. Got it though, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Latchy -  if your problem is solved you can mark it as answer by selecting the tick mark present in left of my answer. It will be useful for the future readers

Answer (score 0):

how about joining on a temp table?

`DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS categoryIDs;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categoryIDs as(
 select t.categoryID from
 (select categoryID from table where distinct(categoryID) >=4 group by categoryID)t );`